# Merging two files, one column at a time

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, merge, data

I have 2 large files (3000 columns, 15000 rows) of the following format

file1 (tab-separated):

```
1/0 0/0 0/0
0/0 1/1 0/0
1/1 0/1 0/0
```

file2 (tab-separated):

```
3 5 2
1 7 10
3 4 3
```

I'd like to combine the values from the first column of each file with a ":" separator, then move on to the second, third, etc. columns. 
Desired output (tab-separated):

```
1/0:3 0/0:5 0/0:2
0/0:1 1/1:7 0/0:10
1/1:3 0/1:4 0/0:3
```

Efficiency isn't critical, so any language is fine. I apologize if this has been asked before.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this? Worked with your sample data:

```
paste  file{1,2} | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF/2; i++){printf "%s:%s\t",$i,$(NF/2+i)};printf "\n"}'
1/0:3   0/0:5   0/0:2
0/0:1   1/1:7   0/0:10
1/1:3   0/1:4   0/0:3
```

Comment: I love paste. +1

Comment: Fair enough @glennjackman; I'll amend my response.

Comment: Yes! Worked perfectly! Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 9):

```
awk '{
    getline f2 < "file2"
    split(f2, a)
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) 
        printf "%s:%s\t", $i, a[i]
    print ""
}' file1
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, although I prefer the simplicity of tink's response.

Comment: @JonDegner then if that answer (or this one) solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the check mark to the left. That will mark the question as answered and is the way thanks are expressed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 6):

A slightly different approach:

```
paste -d: <(xargs -n1 <file1) <(xargs -n1 <file2) | xargs -n 3
```

Comment: I upvoted this, but just realised that the **-n 3** part only works on the sample provided. Column count needs to be modified to accommodate the actual data.

Comment: @tink Obviously, yes. You could calculate the column count with something like `head -n1 | wc -w`, however.

Comment: Heh. That wasn't meant for you to respond, I'm well aware of how to work around it ... just an explanation that your answer should have one less upvote :}